# Problem in Rationalization

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio

The Question is :

If $1 < a <2$ then 
$\sqrt{a - 2 \sqrt{a - 1}} - \sqrt{a + 2 \sqrt{a - 1}}$ can be:

A) $2$

B)$-2 \sqrt{a-1}$

C) $0$

D) $\sqrt{a-1}$

I have tried solving it a number of times but failed every time. 
I took $\sqrt{a-1}$ as b then tried to rationalise by multiplying with unity ($\sqrt{a-2b}$ with $\sqrt{a+2b}$ and vice versa). However, after a few steps I always arrived at the question itself not the answer.

Can someone please help me with this sum?

Comment: Hint:  square the expression, keeping track of the fact that $a-2<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k=\sqrt{a-2\sqrt{a-1}}-\sqrt{a+2\sqrt{a-1}}$$

square both sides and get:

$$k^2=2a-2\sqrt{a^2-4(a-1)}=2a-2|a-2|$$

once $1<a<2$ then $|a-2|=2-a$, so

$$k^2=2a-2(2-a)=4a-4\to k=\pm2\sqrt{a-1}$$

but $k<0$ because $\sqrt{a-2\sqrt{a-1}}<\sqrt{a+2\sqrt{a-1}}$, so

$$k=-2\sqrt{a-1}$$

Comment: Can you explain this part:  1<a<2 then |a−2|=2−a|a−2|=2−a

Comment: @Abcd: because $|a-2|=a-2$ if $a-2>0\to a>2$ and $|a-2|=-(a-2)=2-a$ if $a-2<0\to a<2$. Once $1<a<2$ then we must to choose $|a-2|=2-a$

Comment: Actually, I don't know this concept therefore I am getting confused. I can't understand what is happening **after** you found k^2's value.

Comment: Any alternative method that can be followed after that step?

Comment: @Abcd: I'm just using some basic stuff. First basic knowlegde: $|x|=x$ if $x\ge 0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$. Second basic knowlegde: $\sqrt{a-2\sqrt{a-1}}<\sqrt{a+2\sqrt{a-1}}$ because $a-2\sqrt{a-1}<a+2\sqrt{a-1}$. If you are getting confused about those issues I recommend you study them before go foward.